# Firebase Firestore Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the data from my subcollection data.

This is my code

```
database.collection("classes")
                        .document("classId")
                        .collection("subjects")
                        .document("subId")
                        .collection("materials")

                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                        materials.clear();
                        for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot:value.getDocuments()){
                            MatModel model = snapshot.toObject(MatModel.class);
                            model.setMatId(snapshot.getId());
                            materials.add(model);
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }
                });
```

Please support me to retrieve data from materials by using Auto Id

Here is a screenshot of my firestore data [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXhgX.png) & [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IAGf.png)

Comment: Need your support please help

Comment: Have you stored the `classId` and the `subId` in variables? Can you show us what you have tried? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo sir, where i can share full code with you?

Comment: There is no need for the full code, just the code where you are saving those IDs in variables.

Comment: @AlexMamo sir , i have stored only subId in SubjectModel.java

Comment: @AlexMamo sir, String subId = getIntent().getStringExtra("subId");
        String classId = getIntent().getStringExtra("classId");
                database.collection("classes")
                        .document("6thClass")
                        .collection("subjects")
                        .document("subId")
                        .collection("materials")

Comment: You need both in order to create a correct path.

Comment: @AlexMamo sir, could you please edit my code. I will be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `collectionGroup`.

First, you will need to add below fields to `material` document for query correctly: `classId` and `subId`.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Using collectionGroup:

```
firestore.collectionGroup("materials").whereEqualTo("classId", "real-class-id").whereEqualTo("subId", "real-sub-id").get()
       .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
           // ...
         }
   });
```

Comment: Sir actually i am trying to build an lms application

Comment: What is lms? This answer fit your requirements with Android Firebase Firestore.

Comment: Sir, i want to retrieve data by using Auto Id which is different for each document

Comment: Use a collection group query to retrieve documents from a collection group instead of from a single collection. You can try it, i'm 100% sure it works with your question. You can check more example from Reference link above.